# jQuery Uncheck other checkbox on one checked from same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, unchecked

Hello
I would like to tell you that I know there are lots of solved example on stack overflow regarding the same issues.But My query is bit complex and make me sick.I have large number of table that consist of 10 rows and 9 columns.
All I want is when user check the NONE checkbox for STROKE, other checkbox unchecked from the same row.I have to do it for every row.
and if Other checkbox checked (**user can check multiple either PARENT,UNCLE,OTHERS,etc.**),**NONE** checkbox will unchecked.
**Incase of query ask me.**
I am trying from last 2 days for the same, but can successed in it.
Please Help me 
Thanks in advance.

HEART     NONE     PARENT     UNCLE/AUNT     GRANDPARENT    OTHERS
===============================================================
STROKE    [image]                [image]                     [image]                           [image]                        [image]
ATTACK     [image]                [image]                     [image]                           [image]                        [image]
B.P.             [image]                [image]                     [image]                           [image]                        [image]

BLOOD     NONE     PARENT     UNCLE/AUNT     GRANDPARENT    OTHERS
===============================================================
ANEMIA    [image]                [image]                     [image]                           [image]                        [image]
IMMUNE   [image]                [image]                     [image]                           [image]                        [image]
LUKEMIA   [image]                [image]                     [image]                           [image]                        [image]

Comment: @guradio, thankyou for your reply, but I have to check multiple from parent,uncle,grandparent,others.
You can say either none or multiple from other columns.

Comment: this is the task that I have to do it.
Actually this is the medical table , suppose user has some blood related form has to fill, Parent and grandparents and uncle/aunt effected from LUKEMIA or no one is effected from given column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same class for same row.In each row you can give different class name and do further same.I given you one row the sample.

```js
$(function(){
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
if($(this).prop('checked') == true && $(this).attr('class')=='none'){

$(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
$(this).prop('checked', false);
});
$(this).prop('checked',true);

}
else{
$(this).closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
$(this).closest('.none').prop('checked',false);
});
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='0'>
<tr><th>HEART</th><th>NONE</th><th>PARENT</th><th>UNCLE/AUNT</th><th>GRANDPARENT</th><th>OTHERS</th><tr>
<tr><td>STROKE</td><td><input type='checkbox' class='none'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='stroke'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='stroke'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='stroke'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='stroke'></td></tr>
<tr><td>ATTACK</td><td><input type='checkbox' class='none'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='attack'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='attack'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='attack'></td><td><input type='checkbox' class='attack'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Brother, I said , I have to do it for every row.As I mentioned 
"**I have large number of table that consist of 10 rows and 9 columns.**"
cant use direct the class name, I know I should use **$("input:checkbox").each(function(){** to control over every checkbox row.

Comment: ya give the same class name for same row and it will work for any no of rows

Comment: let me give you the URL, you can take an idea then
http://www.codenomad.biz/ssa-agency/info/

Comment: no. Your logic make checkbox functions like radio button, I can't check multiple checkboxes from either parents, others, uncle.

Comment: i understood what you are expecting..hope this will help you..check updated one

Comment: @lalith...I did it...You can do it too. :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".checkAll").on("change",function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")) 
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".check").prop('checked',true);
   else
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".check").prop('checked',false);

});
```

```css
td:first-child{
background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />check All1</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" />check 1</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" />check 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  class="checkAll"  />check All2</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  class="check" />check 2</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  class="check"/>check 2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Farhad...Thankyou for your reply, let me give you the URL, you can take an idea then codenomad.biz/ssa-agency/info

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to uncheck all the closest checkboxes and recheck the clicked one. (Works with tables)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
          });  
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work ;)

```
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="none" value="" id="none">
        <input type="checkbox" name="parent" value="" id="parent" class="otherThanNone">
        <input type="checkbox" name="uncle" value="" id="uncle" class="otherThanNone">
        <input type="checkbox" name="aunt" value="" id="aunt" class="otherThanNone">
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if($('#none').prop('checked')==false){
                $('#none').click(function(){
                    for(var i=0; i<3; ++i){
                        if($('.otherThanNone').eq(i).prop('checked')==true){
                            $('.otherThanNone').eq(i).prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            $('#parent').click(function(){
                $('#none').prop('checked', false);
                console.log('a');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @cardan, You are very close to it, this functionality is for only 1 row, I have more than 100 rows., how can I justify it. Please put some more idea in your logic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Checkbox selection</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>HEART</th>
        <th>NONE</th>
        <th>PARENT</th>
        <th>UNCLE/AUNT</th>
        <th>GRANDPARENT</th>
        <th>OTHERS</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>STROKE</td>
        <td class="strokeTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="heart"></td>
        <td class="strokeTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="none"></td>
        <td class="strokeTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="parent"></td>
        <td class="strokeTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="uncle"></td>
        <td class="strokeTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="grandparent"></td>
        <td class="strokeTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="others"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ATTACK</td>
        <td class="attackTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="heart"></td>
        <td class="attackTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="none"></td>
        <td class="attackTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="parent"></td>
        <td class="attackTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="uncle"></td>
        <td class="attackTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="grandparent"></td>
        <td class="attackTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="others"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>B.P.</td>
        <td class="bpTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="heart"></td>
        <td class="bpTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="none"></td>
        <td class="bpTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="parent"></td>
        <td class="bpTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="uncle"></td>
        <td class="bpTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="grandparent"></td>
        <td class="bpTD"><input type="checkbox" class="Strokeclass" name="others"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.Strokeclass',function(){

        var js_class = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        var js_slected = $(this).attr('name');

        if(js_slected == 'none')
        {
            $( '.'+js_class ).each(function( ) {
                if($(this).children().attr('name') != 'none')
                {$(this).children().prop('checked', false);}
            });
        }
        else if(js_slected == 'others')
        {
            $( '.'+js_class ).each(function( ) {
                if($(this).children().attr('name') == 'none')
                {$(this).children().prop('checked', false);}
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".checkAll").on("change",function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")) 
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".check").prop('checked',true);
   else
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".check").prop('checked',false);

});
```

```css
td:first-child{
background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />check All1</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" />check 1</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" />check 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="checkAll"  />check All2</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="check" />check 2</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  class="check"/>check 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).